# Delphi IXMLDocument remove XPath result node

Tags: xml, delphi, xpath

I search for some nodes with xpath and want to remove these from the document. Is there a way to do it?
The problem is that xpath in delphi results IDOMNode and not IXMLNode.
Can I get the "original" IXMLNode back?
The code is basically this  - searching in IXMLNode N, using Expr for xpath.

```
var
  XPathDOMNodeList: IDOMNodeList;
  DN : IDomNode;

begin  
  if Assigned(N) and
     Supports(N.DOMNode, IDOMNodeSelect, DOMNodeSelect) then
  begin
    XPathDOMNodeList := DOMNodeSelect.selectNodes( Expr );
    if Assigned( XPathDOMNodeList ) and ( XPathDOMNodeList.length > 0 ) then
    begin
      DN := _XPathDOMNodeList.item[ 0 ];

      // now how to remove original IXMLNode matching DN ???    

    end;
  end;
...
```

Comment: Which version of the MSXml type library import unit and Delphi are you using?  Have you tried calling QueryInterface on the DomNodes in your list to retrieve their IXMLNode interfaces?

Comment: @MartynA that will not work, as the `IDOMNode` object is different from the `IXMLNode` object, so querying an `IDOMNode` for `IXMLNode` (and vice versa) will fail. To get the `IXMLNode` that is associated with an `IDOMNode`, you would have to iterate through the `IXMLDocument` looking for the `IXMLNode` whose `DOMNode` property returns the target `IDOMNode`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau>  Thanks, Remy.  I had a vague recollection that there was a simple way to traverse from one to the other, but obviously not.

Comment: Thank you, but traversing and matching IXMLNode's DOMNode does not work with any of the 3 dom vendor implementations I tested /MS,Omni,ADom/. I tried comparing several ways the interface objects, neither gave a match. I put an answer below that works.

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it this way: first convert the IDOMNode to IXMLNode with a method found somewhere, then set a random attribute for this so it can be searched with traversing the doc. It works for Element nodes at least, that's what I needed.
I don't exactly understand how the first conversion step works, but it does.

```
function xmlDomNodeToXMLNode( N : IDOMNode ):IXMLNode; overload;
var
  intfDocAccess : IXmlDocumentAccess;
  doc: TXMLDocument;
begin
  if N = NIL then
    Result := NIL
  else begin
    if Supports( N.OwnerDocument, IXmlDocumentAccess, intfDocAccess) then
      doc := intfDocAccess.DocumentObject
    else
      doc := _xpathdoc as TXMLDocument; // _xpathdoc was used before for XPath query
    Result := TXmlNode.Create( N, nil, doc );
  end;
end;


var
  _an,_av : string;

function xmlDOMNodeToXMLNode( D : IXMLDocument; DN : IDOMNode ):IXMLNode; overload;
  function GetIt2( N : IXMLNode ):IXMLNode;
  var
    i : integer;
  begin
    if N.HasAttribute( _an ) and ( N.GetAttribute( _an ) = _av ) then
      Result := N
    else begin
      for i := 0 to N.ChildNodes.Count-1 do
      begin
        Result := GetIt2( N.ChildNodes[i] );
        if Assigned( Result ) then
          Exit;
      end;
    end;
  end;

var
  N : IXMLNode;
  i : integer;
begin
  N := xmlDomNodeToXMLNode( DN );
  _an := Format( 'a%d', [ random(1000000) ] );
  _av := Format( 'v%d', [ random(1000000) ] );
  N.SetAttribute( _an, _av );

  Result := GetIt2( D.DocumentElement );

  for i := 0 to N.AttributeNodes.Count-1 do
    if N.AttributeNodes[i].NodeName = _an then
    begin
      N.AttributeNodes.Remove( N.AttributeNodes[i] );
      break;
    end;
end;


....

  XMLNode := xmlDOMNodeToXMLNode( Doc, DOMNode );
  XMLNode.ParentNode.ChildNodes.Remove( XMLNode );
```